# C++ socket reading side reads all messages concatenated

Tags: c#, c++, c, sockets, winsock2

Hi I have a socket programming with C# Socket Server and C++ Socket Client.

Server I use `Socket.Send(bytes[])` to send message

CPP Client side i use `recv(socket,buffer,length,flags)` 
But in server if i send multiple messages concurrently on the client side i recieve all messages as concatenated.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
var bytes= GetBytes("msg"+i);
theSocket.Send(bytes);
}
```

C++ Socket CLient:

```
Thread.Start()
{
   var msg = recv(theSocketClient,buffer,1024,0);
   ProcessMessageFromSocket(msg);
}
```

Expected is: 
    process msg1 then 
    Process msg2... Process msg10 
Actual: 
    processMessage(msg1msg2msg3...msg10 );

What i am missing?
my attempts to fix this:
1. C# NetworkStream.Flush()  -- Even after this it gives me concatenated strings
2. CPP Everytime after finishing the read i erase the buffer (but the actual socket has data concatenated so this did not help)

Comment: You have to remember that TCP is a streaming protocol, there's no beginning or end to the stream, data just flows. If you need to separate between messages you have to do it yourself.

Comment: For example IRC uses `\r\n` (Carriage return then line feed) to separate messages.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal for it to work this way.  It's up to you to define your own protocol for splitting up data, for example you might to choose to start each transmission with 4 bytes telling you how long that transmission is.

Answer (score 1):

Simples - TCP cannot transfer any messages longer than one byte - it's an octet/byte stream.

If you want to transfer messages longer than one byte, you need another protocol on top of TCP.

Comment: ..and yes, I know it's a multi-dup, but it's easier to answer than find the dups.

Comment: I'd rather kill all these questions and point them to a TCP FAQ. I can tell that the OP is not using the return value of recv although he has posted no relevant code! Isn't that depressing?! Always the same error. I could create a script posting the same message to all new TCP questions and be right 50% of the time.